# require is undefind in rollup

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

I use rollup.js this is my code:

```
import d3 from 'd3';
console.log(d3);
```

this is my config:

```
import nodeResolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
export default {
    input: 'src/test.js',
    external:[
        'd3'// external
    ],
    output: {
        file: 'dist/test.js',
        format: 'umd',
        paths: {
            d3: 'https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min'// d3 paths
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve(),
        commonjs()
    ]
};
```

this is the result js:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(require('https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min')) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min'], factory) :
    (global = global || self, factory(global.d3));
}(this, function (d3) { 'use strict';
...
}));
```

then when I use this js,`d3` is undefined.
I see `require` and `defined` is undefined.

whats wrong?

Comment: Try
    
    nodeResolve({browser: true})

Comment: Unfortunately, it is invalid